# Finding all the data for which no associated data present without subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1

I have two tables `users` & `contacts`

users

```
| id         | name        | last_name    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |      John   |    Abraham
| 2          |      Tom    |    column    
| 3          |      Bob    |    Warner     
| 4          |      Smith  |    Warne   
| 5          |      Brad   |    Pitt
```

contacts

```
| id         | user_id    | contact       |active     | category_id  |
|:-----------|-----------:|:-------------:|:---------:|:------------:|
| 1          |      1      |    132423    |    false  |     2   
| 2          |      1      |    131423    |    true   |     3
| 3          |      1      |    142423    |    true   |     1
| 4          |      2      |    132413    |    true   |     1
| 5          |      2      |    132425    |    false  |     2
| 6          |      2      |    131420    |    true   |     3
| 7          |      3      |    131323    |    true   |     3
| 8          |      3      |    332423    |    true   |     1
| 9          |      3      |    232423    |    false  |     2
| 10         |      4      |    132523    |    false  |     1
```

I want users for category 1 who have no active `(false)` OR users who don't have contacts for that category as well contacts like following

```
| id         | name        | last_name    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 4          |      Smith  |    Warne   
| 5          |      Brad   |    Pitt
```

I tried something like following but it didn't work

```
User.includes(:contacts).where(contacts: {user_id: nil, category_id: 1 })
```

I can do it using two different queries, but didn't get how to write it in a single query

```
u_ids = Conatct.where(category_id: 1, active: true).pluck(:user_id)
users = User.where.not(id: u_ids)
```

Comment: `User.eager_load(:contacts).where(contacts: {id: nil, category_id: 1 })`

eager_load does a left outer join on 'contacts' table.  For all of users that are not associated with the contacts table - the contacts.id will end up nil for this query

Answer (score 0):

```
User.eager_load(:contacts).where(contacts: {id: nil, category_id: 1 })
```

eager_load does a left outer join on 'contacts' table. For all of users that are not associated with the contacts table - the contacts.id will end up nil for this query